# OWIN Already Authenticated from another project/website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, model-view-controller, owin

I am developing two separate MVC apps. 
For both I have implemented OWIN... something like this:

```
  var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        this.AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            AllowRefresh = true,
            IsPersistent = rememberMe,
            ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7)
        }, identity);
```

My issue: If I login to APP1 and then I go to APP2, I am automatically logged in on APP2.

Comment: private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager => this.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;

Comment: If I understand correctly, you currently have 2 different urls and when you log onto one you are also logged on the second one ?

Comment: @Alexandre YES. I have two different MVC websites, but If I login to one of them, I am automatically logged in to the other. (if I use the same browser) - they somehow share the owin cookies... or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your `web.config` file in each project have an explicitly defined `<machinekey>`?

I.e.

```
<machineKey decryptionKey="[some value]" validationKey="[some value]" />
```

If both sites are on the same domain (website1.domain.com , website2.domain.com), the cookie will persist, and an attempt to decrypt will be made. So if both config files have the key defined and are the same, it will assume authentication.

This depends on how you have your authentication defined though, and may not be the case.

Comment: Yep, this solved my issue.I used it in the past (some 6-7 years ago), but couldn't remember it exactly. Thanks!